# Heroku upload changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I make some changes in local files, how can I deploy the new version?
if I type git push heroku master, it's say everything up to date, but the application wasn't changed.

Comment: did you commit the local changes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably need to commit your changes first.

Run `git commit -a -m "updated some files"`

then run `git push....`

Answer (score 0):

So you’re on a git repo with a remote repo named heroku?

Did you commit your changes, and afterwards push?
They have to be commited locally so you can push them.

When you clone a repository with git the remote repository you cloned from will be added as “origin”, then a simple git push will push to the origin.
If that’s not the case, you can use the name of another/your remote repository you added first, or it’s URL.

Also see the doc for git push: http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html

Comment: Heroku is a SaaS platform.